# Run browser with absolute local path from batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, browser, asynchronous

I want to start a browser (Chrome, in this case) and open a page that is located on my computer, then continue executing other commands. Right now  I have this:

```
@echo off

if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" (
    cmd /C "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "%cd%\MyPage\index.htm"
)
:: More commands here

pause
exit
```

And of course, it says the syntax is incorrect. I am stuck here and I don't know how to do it. It would also be great to open the same file in the same tag if I execute the batch multiple times (instead of opening a new tab each time) but I don't know if Chrome, at least, has this command available. Yet, for now the problem is that I cannot run the browser "asynchronously" and move to the next command in the batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced `cmd /c` with `start ""`

```
@echo off
if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" (
    start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "%cd%\MyPage\index.htm"
)
:: More commands here

pause
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `cmd /C`

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -- "%cd%\MyPage\index.htm"
```

Chrome's open format can be found here `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command`